# Does not show Toast message after image is uploaded successfully

Tags: java, android

My current code uploads image successfully but still it does not show Toast message which says `Image uploaded successfully`. How can I show toast message after image is uploaded successfully?

Here is my code

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Camera.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);
                        new Thread() {
                            public void run() {
                                try {
                                    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "File is uploading...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    if(imageUpload(globalUID, largeImagePath)) {
                                         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                     } else {
                                         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error uploading image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                     }
                                } catch (Exception e) {

                                }

                            }
                        }.start();
```

here is imageUpload method

```
public boolean imageUpload(String uid, String imagepath) {
    boolean success = false;
    //Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);

    byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();
    String ba1=Base64.encodeToString(ba, 0);

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image",ba1));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uid", uid));

    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.example.info/androidfileupload/index.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if(response != null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File uploaded successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            success = true;
        }
        is = entity.getContent();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }
    dialog.dismiss();
    return success;
}
```

Comment: Try your `Activityname.this` instead of `getApplicationContext()` in your `Toast`

Comment: Still not showing Toast message after using MyActivity.this

Comment: Try add some log to see if the Toast line is being entered. if(response != null) {
Log.d("TAG", "response not null"); if it doesn't then the problem is not about the Toast.

Comment: [Try this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4210482/940096)

Comment: @NunoGonçalves after adding Log as you mention it shows `response not null` in logcat

Comment: `Camera` is your activity? May be its your Activity problem. Try to change your activity name. And, use that renamed activity.this

Comment: this might be a long shot, but did you place the activity on your manifest? Try to add a toast outside of the method, just to see if it's working.

Comment: @NunoGonçalves yes I add this activity in manifest. Toast is working in this class because other Toasts are working properly.

Comment: Are you sure you arent trying to toast your message inside an asyncTask or a different thread other than the main one?

Comment: @al0neevenings : let me known both Toast not appearing ? means put Log.d("STATUS : -",success); and check success value on onClick before making any change in your code as suggested by all

Comment: No one's answer working? Or didn't try anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> you are trying to display Toast in non UI Thread so can't see Toast

Use  [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) after completion of Task to show Toast.its better to use [AsyncTask.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Using AsyncTask,add your `imageUpload code in DoinBackground(...) method and return boolean to onPostExxecute(),and You can display Toast in OnPostExecute Method.`

Comment: @SamirMangroliya maybe some nope that don't understand to difference between UI thread and worker thread.

Comment: +1,your asking correct.because,must use handler (or)  AsyncTask for upload or download operations for the process completed event only detecting!

Comment: @SamirMangroliya yes you right, i wrote that man that downvoted you maybe don't understand difference between UI tread and non UI.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to implement [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) which is known as **Painless Threading** in android.

And in your case, you can call imageUpload() inside the `doInBackground()` method, display Toast from `onPostExecute()` method, no need to take care about Threads.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know this is right or wrong. You can try like this -

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(DummyUsageActivity.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);
    this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "File is uploading...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if(imageUpload(globalUID, largeImagePath)) {
                     Toast.makeText(DummyUsageActivity.this, "Image uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 } else {
                     Toast.makeText(DummyUsageActivity.this, "Error uploading image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    });
}
```

I think this will work. As per users - [Paresh Mayani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/379693/paresh-mayani) & [Samir Mangroliya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/776244/samir-mangroliya) suggestion for [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) also better to do this.